# Display Vim intermediate commands

Tags: command, vim

In `vimtutor` Lesson 2.1: DELETION COMMANDS, there is a note after the #4 item:

> The letter `d` will appear on the last line of the screen as you type it. Vim is waiting for you to type `w`. If you see another character than `d` you typed something wrong; press `<ESC>` and start over.

However, I do not see intermediate commands in the last line as the note says. How do I enable this? What option should I set in my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use

```
:set showcmd
```

That will display the commands as you type it in Vim.
The same can also be put into .vimrc

Comment: Although I have edited my `.vimrc`,  the commands still do not show up. What might be the problem?

Comment: @vishy1618: This isn't a complete answer, since it doesn't work in `.vimrc`, when we append `set showcmd` in .vimrc.  Would like a complete answer to this question, also I can't understand why it's not working in .vimrc. I have sourced the `.vimrc` file and also created a new shell session too, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This 'last line' is the line at bottom of screen.
If you don't see this you may have trouble with (Linux?) terminal setting.

If you use terminal on Linux system, try to invoke command `export TERM=Linux` before running Vim.

Comment: I'm using OS X. If I type in `:`, I would see it normally, but not the other commands.